# Study error: lowest and lowestbar length argument must be > 0

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to counter a weird problem (bug?) in Pine. I want to get the offset to the bar of the lowest value because I need to know both offset and value so i can draw a line.

```
bool mwIsAnchorBot            = mw < -60
int  mwBarsSinceAnchBot       = int(min(5000, barssince(mwIsAnchorBot)))
int  loLowestBarsSinceAnchBot = lowestbars(low, max(1, mwBarsSinceAnchBot))
```

This returns a study error

> Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0.0) in the lowest bar function. It must be > 0

How is this possible? I have set a minimal value of 1 and a maximum value of 5000? And why is it received as float? (0.0)? I never ever declared a float and explicitly declare integers and booleans.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles on this question, I found out that barssince returns `na` if the condition was not found.

To avoid my problem I had to wrap `nz` around it:

```
int(min(5000, nz(barssince(mwIsAnchorBot))))
```